# Pyplot legend shows marks info

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I need to plot a series of data related to different group:

```
y_values = [y1,y2,y3...]
height = [x1,x2,x3...]
weight = [z1,z2,z3...]
income = [w1,w2,w3...]
```

All data are associated to the same y_value. In order to distinguish them on the plot I used:

```
plt.plot(height[0],y_values[0],'b.')
plt.plot(income[0],y_values[0],'b*')
...
```

Now I want to have a legend that shows the meaning of each marker:

```
. height
* income
...
```

How can I realize it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the label argument in combination with legend:

```
plt.plot(height[0],y_values[0],'b.', label='Height')
plt.legend()
```